# Output of the #error directive in C

Tags: c

I have a piece of code, to throw an error during compilation using the #error directive, checking for the chip type present on the board. When I run it, I get an output that is something like below:

```
errorchk.c:9:2: error: #error "I can't run"
```

I was expecting to see an error like this:

```
errorchk.c:9: error: "I can't run"
```

I'm not able to figure out what is the error in line 9 (if any), that is shown below.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define X 2
void main()
{
  int x=6;
    if(x>5)
    {
#if X>1
#error "I can't run"
#endif
    }
}
```

Could someone please clarify if the message on the stdout is as expected? essentially,  is the **"#error"** supposed to be printed in the error-string?

Answer (score 4):

The C standard doesn't specify exactly what the compiler should output, only that the tokens after `#error` must be included in the output. The output you get is "conforming". Different compilers can do different things.

For instance, `clang` has a different format, but it is conforming too:

```
$ cat t.c
#error hello
$ clang -c t.c
t.c:1:2: error: hello
#error hello
 ^
1 error generated.
```

The error is printed as you want it, with extra context.

Reference: C11 draft, §6.10.5 *Error directive*

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # error pp-tokensopt new-line
> ```
>
> causes the implementation to produce a diagnostic message that includes the specified
> sequence of preprocessing tokens.

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected output (to `stderr`, not `stdout`).

Comment: I guess I used the wrong term. I should have been a little more elaborate. I'm running a build for my project, where it checks for a peripheral chip. And the build is expected to break under certain conditions, and the error displayed on the terminal where the build was running.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it is a useful part of the diagnostic to know that it is a message thrown by a #error directive rather than a built-in compiler message.  Either way the actual format of compiler diagnostics of any kind is not mandated by the language standard.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm not able to figure out what is the error in line 9"

Macros that use directives starting with # are run before the rest of the code is compiled, let alone executed.

The error is clear. X is defined to be 2 when the preprocessor reaches line 9, so the condition is true, and the #error directive fires, stopping compilation.

It may appear to some that the value of x is 6 at that point. But the C code is not being executed. It is not even compiled yet. The X and x have nothing to do with each other.

A more interesting example would use the same case, either X or x, in both places.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define X 2
void main()
{
    int X=6;
    if(X>5)
{
#if X>1
#error "I can't run"
#endif
    }
}
```

In that case, they are still not the same thing. Instead, the preprocessor would replace every occurrence of the character X in the source with the character 2. Even if you removed the error directive, the code would not compile because the line `int 2=6;` is not valid C.